# Where to place common code in Phalcon-based site that is called each page load

Tags: php, phalcon

I have code that I want to run on every page load, such as looking up menu items, looking up the users details etc. These will be displayed on partial views that make up the main view.

Where do I place this code so that it can fill my partial views with each page load? I know I can just add the code to the top of the partial view itself, but this doesn't really follow the MVC pattern.

Is there a function that is always called that I can hook into in my base controller?

Comment: Model-view-controller is only a means to and end. IIt's not a fixed framework making this question too broad to answer to or comment to.

Comment: @TomKriek- true, but how would most people following the MVC pattern approach this problem?

Comment: You would include the code you would want to run on the initial load of the page. Before the autoload of the classes or views.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base viewmodel for the repeated code and make other viewmodels inherit from it.

Comment: ViewModel? I'm not using ViewModels.. do you mean Controller? Your answer isn't really complete- it only tells me half the solution. Is there a function or something that is always called in the base?

Answer (score 0):

> ...such as looking up menu items, looking up the users details etc

You're a bit unclear about the *type* of information you want to load: in case the info is a view-component then indeed you should create a base-view and inherit from it or include it (composition) in any other view.

But, in case it is "user-information" - the data should live in a model-component that again, may live as "base-model" object that is included in other model components.